# Cannot load custom class with URLClassLoader in JavaFX JavaScript

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to get my custom class loaded in FXML JS.

First of all I've added `URLClassLoader` with my JAR to the FXMLLoader instance:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setController(TabController.this);

URLClassLoader fxmlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) loader.getClassLoader();
loader.setClassLoader(URLClassLoader.newInstance((URL[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(new URL[]{ new File("/home/sk_/projects/mjolnirr/.hive/static/calculator/origJar.jar").toURI().toURL() }, fxmlClassLoader.getURLs())));
```

And then in FXML JavaScript:

```
importClass(com.mjolnirr.sample.SomeTestClass);
```

It fails with error:

```
sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Function importClass must be called with a class; had "[JavaPackage com.mjolnirr.sample.SomeTestClass]" instead. (<Unknown source>#2) in <Unknown source> at line number 2
```

Anyone faced that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found one hack solution [there](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/05/tip-add-resources-dynamically-to-a-classloader/). In short - I've just added my URL to the system classloader dynamically, like this:

```
public static void addURLToSystemClassLoader(URL url) throws IntrospectionException {
    URLClassLoader systemClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Class<URLClassLoader> classLoaderClass = URLClassLoader.class;

    try {
        Method method = classLoaderClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(systemClassLoader, new Object[]{url});
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        throw new IntrospectionException("Error when adding url to system ClassLoader ");
    }
}
```

And then in my render method

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setController(TabController.this);

try {
    addURLToSystemClassLoader(new URL("hive://" + pageURL.getHost() + ":" + pageURL.getPort() + "/" + pageURL.getApplicationName() + "/origJar.jar"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it looks like a bad practise.

I think that the original problem is that - JavaFX scripting engine has differect class loader, FXML loader doesn't pass it's own to the script engine. Anyone knows how to set the classloader for the script engine?

Answer (score 0):

How about explicitly setting the class loaded for the current thread to the new class loader?

For example:

```
URL[] urlsForJarFiles = getUrls();
ClassLoader myClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urlsForJarFiles, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread.setContextClassLoader(myClassLoader);
```